# CSS transition not working properly after the cursor hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a header where there are some links and a company logo which is in "flex, align-item:center and justify-content:space-between". I have made CSS transition in links. Transition which is not working is something like that whenever user hover the link all four side corners of border will be visible and when the user leave the hover it will be invisible is not working because when we leave the cursor from the link the border starts appearing and I am not able to solve it.

NOTE:- Second transition which is flip the text is working fine.

```js
const menuItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item')];

    menuItems.forEach(item => {
        let word = item.children[0].children[0].innerText.split('');
        item.children[0].innerHTML = '';
        word.forEach((letter, idx) => {
            item.children[0].innerHTML += `<span style="--index: ${idx};">${letter}</span>`;
        })
        let cloneDiv = item.children[0].cloneNode(true);
        cloneDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        cloneDiv.style.left = '0';
        cloneDiv.style.top = '0';
        cloneDiv.style.padding = '10px';
        item.appendChild(cloneDiv)
    });
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
        background: #000;
    }

    .menu a {
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .menu a:hover {
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .menu a:hover:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        left: -2px;
        width: calc(100% + 4px);
        height: calc(100% - 12px);
        background: #000;
        transform: scaleY(1);
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .menu a:hover:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 6px;
        top: -2px;
        height: calc(100% + 4px);
        width: calc(100% - 12px);
        background: #000;
        transform: scaleX(1);
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .menu a div:nth-child(1) {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
    }

    .menu a div:nth-child(2) {
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .header-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 20px 5%;
    }

    .header-container .logo {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .header-container .logo a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    .header-container .logo img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .menu {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .menu .menu-item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 20px
    }

    .menu-item {
        position: relative;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu-item-text {
        position: relative;
        pointer-events: none;
        display: block;
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 2rem
    }

    .menu-item>div:nth-child(1) span {
        will-change: transform;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: 0.5s;
        transition-delay: calc(0.05s * var(--index));
        transform-origin: bottom;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .menu-item>div:nth-child(2) span {
        will-change: transform;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: 0.5s;
        transition-delay: calc(0.05s * var(--index));
        transform-origin: top;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0) rotateX(-90deg);
    }

    .menu-item:hover>div:nth-child(1) span {
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0) rotateX(-90deg);
    }

    .menu-item:hover>div:nth-child(2) span {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) rotateX(0deg);
    }

    span {
        font-size: 1vw;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Company Logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a href="home.php" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Home</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Services</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Start&nbsp; a &nbsp; Project</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Projects</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">About Us</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you apply the 4-corner style only to a:hover.

Here's the corrected code:

```js
const menuItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item')];

    menuItems.forEach(item => {
        let word = item.children[0].children[0].innerText.split('');
        item.children[0].innerHTML = '';
        word.forEach((letter, idx) => {
            item.children[0].innerHTML += `<span style="--index: ${idx};">${letter}</span>`;
        })
        let cloneDiv = item.children[0].cloneNode(true);
        cloneDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        cloneDiv.style.left = '0';
        cloneDiv.style.top = '0';
        cloneDiv.style.padding = '10px';
        item.appendChild(cloneDiv)
    });
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
        background: #000;
    }

    .menu a {
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 3s;
    }


    .menu a:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        left: -2px;
        width: calc(100% + 4px);
        height: calc(100% - 12px);
        background: #000;
        transform: scaleY(1);
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .menu a:hover {
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        transition: 3s;
    }
    .menu a:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 6px;
        top: -2px;
        height: calc(100% + 4px);
        width: calc(100% - 12px);
        background: #000;
        transform: scaleX(1);
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .menu a div:nth-child(1) {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
    }

    .menu a div:nth-child(2) {
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .header-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 20px 5%;
    }

    .header-container .logo {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .header-container .logo a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    .header-container .logo img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .menu {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .menu .menu-item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 20px
    }

    .menu-item {
        position: relative;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu-item-text {
        position: relative;
        pointer-events: none;
        display: block;
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 2rem
    }

    .menu-item>div:nth-child(1) span {
        will-change: transform;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: 0.5s;
        transition-delay: calc(0.05s * var(--index));
        transform-origin: bottom;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .menu-item>div:nth-child(2) span {
        will-change: transform;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: 0.5s;
        transition-delay: calc(0.05s * var(--index));
        transform-origin: top;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0) rotateX(-90deg);
    }

    .menu-item:hover>div:nth-child(1) span {
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0) rotateX(-90deg);
    }

    .menu-item:hover>div:nth-child(2) span {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) rotateX(0deg);
    }

    span {
        font-size: 1vw;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Company Logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a href="home.php" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Home</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Services</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Start&nbsp; a &nbsp; Project</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Projects</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <div>
                    <span class="menu-item-text">About Us</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```